# Installing Rancid on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wget

I'm using [this tutorial](https://isecd.net/monitoring/install-and-configure-rancid-ubuntu-16-04/) to install rancid in ubuntu 18.04, but when I reach the download part I get the file "rancid-3.99.99.tar.gz" not found. I thought that was because of my ubuntu version, so I tried to download rancid 3.7-1 package and I got the same error. Can someone help me?

Some parts are in portuguese, if you don't understand I can translate.

```
root@lorena:~/downloads# wget ftp://ftp.shrubbery.net/pub/rancid/rancid-3.99.99.tar.gz
--2018-09-21 10:24:15--  ftp://ftp.shrubbery.net/pub/rancid/rancid-3.99.99.tar.gz
           => “rancid-3.99.99.tar.gz”
Resolvendo ftp.shrubbery.net (ftp.shrubbery.net)... 129.250.47.99
Conectando-se a ftp.shrubbery.net (ftp.shrubbery.net)|129.250.47.99|:21... conectado.
Acessando como anonymous ... Acesso autorizado!
==> SYST ... feito.    ==> PWD ... feito.
==> TYPE I ... feito.  ==> CWD (1) /pub/rancid ... feito.
==> SIZE rancid-3.99.99.tar.gz ... feito.

==> PASV ... feito.    ==> RETR rancid-3.99.99.tar.gz ... 
O arquivo “rancid-3.99.99.tar.gz” não foi encontrado.
```

Comment: Have a look at the directory you were trying to download from - ftp://ftp.shrubbery.net/pub/rancid/ - you'll note there is no 3.99.99 version available,  maybe they meant 9 as representing a number (*I'm an old cobol coder, so to me 9 means a digit, ie. `pic 99`..* & I just entered your wget url minus the filename into browser & can see what's available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours `rancid` has standard Ubuntu package - `rancid` from [*universe* repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=rancid) (since Ubuntu Trusty Tahr - 14.04 LTS).

By the commands below you will get version 3.7 on your Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rancid # rancid-cgi
```